# How to add all songs in your apple music library to a single playlist at once?

Tags: itunes, music, apple-music, playlist

I figured out a couple of songs get removed from apple music overtime, I want all my library songs in a single playlist so that I can keep an eye on the number of songs I have, currently I have over 2000+ songs in my library, I would like to add all of them in a playlist so that I can continue to update my library with new songs via that playlist (+I can better monitor my library via this playlist i.e. total no. of songs, total playing hours), is there a way to do this without having to select songs one after the other?

Another reason for me wanting all my library songs in a single playlist is for the convenience of exporting my playlist songs to my accounts on alternative music streaming platforms easily e.g. spotify or youtube-music which I find more playlist inclined than apple music

Comment: Can‘t you just go to Tracks list, select all and create a playlist?

Comment: can you please help with screenshots, not seeing anything like that on my iphone

Comment: Ah, you want to do this on your phone, with the Music app?